# Which word should I use in this sentence to indicate Toomer's freedom of choice?

Tags: word-choice

Here is the sentence:

> Although a native son of Negro descent, Toomer was not physically recognized as black and could pass for white.

What I want to say is Toomer had the freedom to choose his racial identity when at social occasions. Which adverb should I add after the word "pass"? I think "willingly" is improper.

Comment: Freely? Easily? Breezily? Unnoticed? Often? Alternately? Cheerfully? Slyly?

Comment: easily sounds best to me but not sure this to "choose his racial identity". You can want to appear as something and have something completely different in your mind.

Comment: @YosefBaskin None of those suggest the notion of active choice that the OP asks about.

Comment: I think "pass" in itself might already suggest what you want; less deliberate would be "could be mistaken for white". The adverbs in the above comments then express how easy it is.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although a native son of Negro descent, Toomer was not physically
> recognized as black and could pass for white **at will**.

**at will** (phrase)

> At whatever time or in whatever way one pleases.
> [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=at%20will%20meaning)

> If you can do something **at will**, you can do it any time you want.
>
> *He can cry at will.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/at-will)

> As one wishes: as or when it pleases or suits oneself
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20will)

---

> In American are all extremes from the tens of thousands who are only
> sociologically Negroes and "pass for white" **at will** to the two million
> or so who seem miraculously without trace of racial admixture.
> [Samuel
> Schmalhousen; *Behold America!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zTNCAAAAIAAJ&q=%22pass%20for%20white%20at%20will%22&dq=%22pass%20for%20white%20at%20will%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBjeqh5qODAxXgMlkFHT35BbcQ6AF6BAgIEAI) (1931)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm taking your advice :)